# ASP.NET Web API routing and action selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a problem with my routing and action selection for my controller.
My routing looks like:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

My controller looks like:

```
[HttpGet]
public Customers GetCustomers()
{
}

[HttpGet]
public Customer GetCustomerDetail(int id)
{
}

[ActionName("orders")]
[HttpGet]
public Orders GetCustomerOrders(int id)
{
}
```

I can call `http://localhost/customers` and I can call `http://localhost/customers/1/orders`.
But when I try to call `http://localhost/customers/1` I'll get the error says "Multiple actions were found that match the request:" (match to GetCustomerDetail and GetCustomerOrders).

Any idea how to solve this problem?

THX

Comment: explicitly call your action, `http://localhost/customers/GetCustomerDetail/1`

Comment: Yeah OK, but this is not what I want to achieve ;-) and it's not logical at all. It should be 'http://localhost/customers/1'.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your routing to be:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}",
    defaults: new { action = "GetCustomers" });

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApiWithIdAndAction",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new { action="GetCustomerDetail" });
```

EDIT:
If all your controller methods follow the same pattern you could do something like the following:

```
[ActionName("default")]
[HttpGet]
public Customers GetCustomers()
{
}

[ActionName("default")]
[HttpGet]
public Customer GetCustomerDetail(int id)
{
}

[ActionName("orders")]
[HttpGet]
public Orders GetCustomerOrders(int id)
{
}
```

And you could then use the one route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "default" });
```

Comment: That sounds like a lot of work if you have more than one controller in this structure. What a mess!!!

Comment: I've added a more generic solution to the answer.